# Selenium OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException in FireFox

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to get started writing Selenium tests, and the first very basic test I write fails with the exception `OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException`.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace WebDriverDemo
{
        class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Url = "http://www.google.com";

        }
    }
}
```

The debugger says I need to download geckodriver.exe and set it up on my PATH variable, which I've done, and I still get the same exception. When I do the same thing with a `ChromeDriver`, it works fine.

Also, according to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver), if I'm using Selenium 3.0 or later, it should be enabled by default. I'm using Selenium 3.0.1 on a Windows 10 computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add the geckodriver location in PATH or add it in the code only, using System.setProperty() method.

Have a look at this below link. It shows the basic code in Java, you would need to write the C# equivalent. But it mentions the steps for using GeckoDriver. If its still not working then please share the error that you get.

http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/

Comment: Well it's working now, I had set it in the PATH variable earlier and I received the same error, but I just tried again without making any changes and it's working as expected. But this is the correct solution regardless, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to install [Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver/) NuGet package which will copy the driver to the bin folder.

Then you can provide path to the current folder to driver ctor to run your tests:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver("./");
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by adding geckodriver.exe to my project and choosing "Copy if newer" for its *Copy to Output Directory* property.

This allows both regular code and NUnit tests to find the driver. No changes to PATH or SetProperty calls required.

Answer (score 1):

As of this post, Visual Studio has a "Web Driver Test for Edge(the HTMLEdge based one)" project as a starting project for Acceptance Testing.

I've found that changing this to using Chrome makes it crash with your stated error... **You can fix this by not passing ChromeOptions to ChromeDriver**. Just pass either `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` or `"./"` into ChromeDriver and everything'll work.

You should see Chrome start up, wait a while, then very fast browse to Bing.com and run the test (it'll flash before your eyes).

Answer (score 0):

Just download the Firefox Driver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

And simply copy the driver exe to bin directory. Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use NuGet Package Manager, you can install Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64 or Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver. It will make the geckodriver.exe available for you in the project, and it will be easy to manage.