# ERROR !!! OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException is showing even tho i have installed all the drivers required

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException . Tried Installing all the drivers but still showing me the error.

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Threading;


namespace lettryanotherone
{
    class EntryPoint
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IWebDriver ChromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();

            ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.OverWorldInnovations.com");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            ChromeDriver.Quit(); 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException in FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475341/selenium-openqa-selenium-driverservicenotfoundexception-in-firefox)

Comment: You can add it through a nuget package and then use a basepath to always call it from the bin dir. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668341/selenium-c-sharp-mstest-chromedriver-exe-does-not-exist-getdirectory-referr/54372244#54372244

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure to download [Chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org) which exactly matches Chrome browser version you're using
2. Unpack `chromedriver.exe` somewhere in operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))
3. That should be it, however you might need to restart your console and/or IDE

Instead of step 2 you can also consider using [ChromeDriverService](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Chrome/ChromeDriverService.cs) class and explicitly provide the location of the `chromedriver.exe` to the ChromeDriver initialization statement.

```
// given path to chromedriver is c:\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(
    ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("c:\\selenium\\webdriver", "chromedriver.exe"));
```

- [Selenium C# Tutorial for Beginners](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/)
- [Selenium with C Sharp](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium+with+C+Sharp)